# Selenium net.serenity.bdd.core.exceptions.SerenityManagedException Element timed out

Tags: angular, selenium, bdd

I am having trouble selecting a **radio** **button** in this form:

```
<form _ngcontent-c4="" novalidate="" class="ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid"> 
   <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="text-center">
      <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="row mt-3">
        <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-sm-12">
          <h1 _ngcontent-c4="">Place of birth?</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="row mt-3">
        <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-md-6">
           <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="live-box">    
              <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="row">
                 <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-sm-12">
                    <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="form-check">
                        <input _ngcontent-c4="" class="form-check-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid" id="city1" name="live" required="" type="radio" value="City">
                        <label _ngcontent-c4="" class="form-check-label" for="materialInline1"></label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="row">
              <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-sm-12">
                <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="img city-img"></div>
               </div>
             </div>
             <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="row mt-10">
                <div _ngcontent-c4="" class="col-sm-12"><p _ngcontent-c4="" class="title1 mb-0">Small city</p>
                <p _ngcontent-c4="" class="small-text1">My home</p>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I declare the WebElement like that:

```
@FindBy(id="city1")
private static WebElement cityRadioButton;
```

and then:

```
waitFor(cityRadioButton);
cityRadioButton.click() - the element cannot be located.
```

When the image with the embedded radio button is not selected the class is like this:

```
form-check-input ng-untouched ng-pristine ng-invalid
```

When the radio button gets selected on the UI, the classname updates to:

`form-check-input ng-untouched ng-valid ng-dirty`.

Any hints or help on how to tackle this will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the exception stack trace ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try with this code :

**city1** might be a dynamic **id**, you can try with the given css selector :

```
@FindBy(css="input[value='City'][name='live']")
private static WebElement cityRadioButton;  

waitFor(cityRadioButton);
cityRadioButton.click();
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but it doesn't work. I've tried similar combinations with xpath for input and value.The stacktrace is straightforward: Timed out after xxxx milliseconds. Increasing the wait time doesn't do anything. Also, all other elements on the page are found without issue. It is this one that is stubborn. The only thing that comes up to my mind is to use some kind of JSExecutor.

Comment: yeah, that might work.. code would be something like `JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", cityRadioButton);`